# Rails model with associated images and selecting main image for this model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, paperclip

I want to ask about, how can you properly select main image from association of images after you update main_image and delete more couple images etc.

I have this code: 

It's the main model:

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :paintings, inverse_of: :gallery
  belongs_to :primary_painting, class_name: 'Painting', required: false
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :paintings, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  before_validation :primary_painting_setup

  private

  def primary_painting_setup
    self.primary_painting = paintings.any? ? paintings.select(&:primary?).first || paintings.first : nil
  end
end
```

And this is associated model:

```
class Painting < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :gallery, inverse_of: :paintings
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: '300x300>', thumb: '100x100>' }, default_url: '/images/:style/missing.png'
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Basically, gallery has main_image on index page, which is chosen from associate paintings.
But f.e. if I delete all images and add a new one and set it as main image. It won't work, because on the stage of `before_validation` I have only old images, which aren't useful for me at all.

Of course I can use a helper or model method such as `gallery.paintings.find(:&main_image_bool)` every time I render a gallery, but it costs too much speed.

Can you advise more proper way to choose this? Maybe there's a **magic** association, that will help.

Comment: How about after_validation or after_save ?

Comment: I think you can't update anything in any model callback

Comment: I mean by calling `update(...)`

Comment: That makes sense, the transaction is over by then. 
How about moving the setup to the Painting and using the belongs_to navigation to set the value in the owner?

Comment: I've tested it, so if you move to before_save it won't work, because parent is updated first. But I'm not so sure if you call `before_validation` on nested association